# Lost functionality of javascript after using bootstap

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-5

Before I linked bootstrap to html file, the buttons were working. I got "uncaught typeerror cannot read property addeventlistener" error. after linking to bootstrap. I fixed the error after reviewing previous suggestions by linking jQuery and using $(document).ready() method. There are three buttons. First one to change color. The second one is  to switch the list. The last one is to do a multiplication. Both first one and the third buttons are working except the second one. The style.css is saved in a separate file.

The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>My Page</title>
    
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"   rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384 rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <body>
            
            <div id="col1" class="col-md-4">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                <button id="change-color">Change Color</button>
            </div>
            <div id="col2" class="col-md-4">
                <ul id="colorlist">
                    <li>Red</li>
                    <li>Green</li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="animalist">
                    <li>dog</li>
                    <li>cat</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" id="switch-list">Switch</button>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="value1" type="text" value="5">
                <input id="value2" type="text" value="6">
                <button id="multiply">Multiply</button>
                <hr>
                <!--empty paragraph-->
                <p id="result"></p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Col1</th>
                        <th>Col2</th>
                        <th>Col3</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td>B</td>
                        <td>C</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    var btnSwitch = document.body.children[1].children[2];
    var colorlist = document.body.children[1].children[0];
    var animallist = document.body.children[1].children[1];
    
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        btnSwitch.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            if (colorlist.style.display != "none") { // If #colorlist is displayed
                colorlist.style.display = "none";    //        Hide #colorlist
                animallist.style.display = "block";    //        Show #animallist
            } else {                                                             //   Else
                animallist.style.display = "none";    //        Hide #animallist
                colorlist.style.display = "block";   //        Show #colorlist
            }
        });

    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var btnChange = document.getElementById("change-color");
        btnChange.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            var col1 = document.getElementById("col1");
            switch (col1.style.color) {
                case "red":
                    col1.style.color = "green";
                    break;
                case "green":
                    col1.style.color = "blue";
                    break;
                case "blue":
                    col1.style.color = "black";
                    break;
                case "black":
                    col1.style.color = "purple";
                    break;
                default:
                    col1.style.color = "red";
                    break;

            }
        });
    });

    var btnMultiply = document.getElementById("multiply");
    var inputValue1 = document.getElementById("value1");
    var inputValue2 = document.getElementById("value2");

    btnMultiply.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var val1 = inputValue1.value;
        var val2 = inputValue2.value;
        if (isNaN(val1) || isNaN(val2)) {
            //replace alert box with DOM manipulation
            //alert("At least one of the values is not a number");
            result.innerHTML = "one or both of the input values is invalid";
            result.style.color = "red";
        } else {
            //alert(val1+" X "+val2+" = "+(val1*val2).toFixed(2));
            result.innerHTML = val1 + " X " + val2 + " = " + (val1 * val2).toFixed(2);
            result.style.color = "green";
        }

            });   

    function validateNumber() {
        if (isNaN(this.value)) {
            this.style.border = "2px solid red";
        } else {
            this.style.border = "";
        }


    }

    inputValue1.addEventListener("keyup", validateNumber)

    inputValue2.addEventListener("keyup", validateNumber)
</script>
</body>

</html>

I appreciate your feedback.

Thanks




I used $(documnent).ready() to fix 2 errors out of three. I couldn't solve the third error by using the same method.
```

Comment: Bootstrap is probably inserting elements into the body. Instead of using numeric indexing of children, give them IDs or classes and use that to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet you only loaded the `CSS` of Bootstrap and this *should* not interfere with your JQuery. I don't know what *did* cause your issue, but my guess is you made some changes in your HTML structure and this interfered with how you have set up the manner in which to return page elements:

```
var btnSwitch = document.body.children[1].children[2];
```

The danger of selecting your elements this way is that a small change in your HTML can break it. Unless you specifically want to target a child or parent of a given element, the better way would be to use:

```
var btnSwitch = document.getElementById('switch-list')
```

It's also much easier to read code! Since you already use `getElementById()` in other parts of your code, I assume you know how it works.

Moving on.

You use  `$(document).ready(function () { ... })` twice in your code. Shouldn't be an issue, but if the first `ready()` method throws an error, the second block will **not** be executed. So if there is no specific need for it, just declare it once. And define your `var`s *inside* the (nameless) function, if you're using it.

You also have a mistake in your HTML, having `div` elements before the open `<body>` tag, but this might happened when you copied your code in your question.

**Fixed example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var btnSwitch = document.getElementById('switch-list')
  var colorlist = document.getElementById('colorlist')
  var animallist = document.getElementById('animalist')
  var btnChange = document.getElementById("change-color")
  var btnMultiply = document.getElementById("multiply")
  var inputValue1 = document.getElementById("value1")
  var inputValue2 = document.getElementById("value2")

  btnSwitch.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (colorlist.style.display != "none") { // If #colorlist is displayed
      colorlist.style.display = "none"; //        Hide #colorlist
      animallist.style.display = "block"; //        Show #animallist
    } else { //   Else
      animallist.style.display = "none"; //        Hide #animallist
      colorlist.style.display = "block"; //        Show #colorlist
    }
  });

  btnChange.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var col1 = document.getElementById("col1");
    switch (col1.style.color) {
      case "red":
        col1.style.color = "green";
        break;
      case "green":
        col1.style.color = "blue";
        break;
      case "blue":
        col1.style.color = "black";
        break;
      case "black":
        col1.style.color = "purple";
        break;
      default:
        col1.style.color = "red";
        break;
    }
  });

  btnMultiply.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var val1 = inputValue1.value;
    var val2 = inputValue2.value;
    if (isNaN(val1) || isNaN(val2)) {
      //replace alert box with DOM manipulation
      //alert("At least one of the values is not a number");
      result.innerHTML = "one or both of the input values is invalid";
      result.style.color = "red";
    } else {
      //alert(val1+" X "+val2+" = "+(val1*val2).toFixed(2));
      result.innerHTML = val1 + " X " + val2 + " = " + (val1 * val2).toFixed(2);
      result.style.color = "green";
    }
  });

  function validateNumber() {
    if (isNaN(this.value)) {
      this.style.border = "2px solid red";
    } else {
      this.style.border = "";
    }
  }

  inputValue1.addEventListener("keyup", validateNumber)
  inputValue2.addEventListener("keyup", validateNumber)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My Page</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384 rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="col1" class="col-md-4">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <button id="change-color">Change Color</button>
        </div>
        <div id="col2" class="col-md-4">
          <ul id="colorlist">
            <li>Red</li>
            <li>Green</li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="animalist">
            <li>dog</li>
            <li>cat</li>
          </ul>
          <button type="button" id="switch-list">Switch</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input id="value1" type="text" value="5">
          <input id="value2" type="text" value="6">
          <button id="multiply">Multiply</button>
          <hr>
          <!--empty paragraph-->
          <p id="result"></p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Col1</th>
              <th>Col2</th>
              <th>Col3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>A</td>
              <td>B</td>
              <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. At first I struggled with your suggestion, but I entered <script src="index.js"></script> before </body> in html file.

Comment: @HusniS You're welcome! Not sure what you meant though. Did you copy the JavaScript from the snippet in a new file called `index.js`? If so, that is perfectly fine and makes it easier to maintain your project.  I assume you got things working. If not, don't hesitate to ask. If my answer was to your satisfaction, please hit "Accept". Thanks!